# future-proofing java version check in ant script

Tags: java, ant

The script provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147850/when-using-ant-how-can-i-define-a-task-only-if-i-have-some-specific-java-version/147890#147890) gave a great way to check if Ant is using Java 6.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project name="project" default="default">

    <target name="default" depends="javaCheck" if="isJava6">
        <echo message="Hello, World!" />
    </target>

    <target name="javaCheck">
        <echo message="ant.java.version=${ant.java.version}" />
        <condition property="isJava6">
            <equals arg1="${ant.java.version}" arg2="1.6" />
        </condition>
    </target>

</project>
```

However, I have good reason to think the next person holding my position may not be a Java programmer and I want to make sure the builds don't fail because of Java 7. Is there any way to pick apart a String or otherwise ask for *Java 6 or higher*?

Comment: What is the reason you need to know the JVM level in your script?

Comment: I'm trying to guard against the Java 5 javac on Mac 10.5. That javac is unaware of the Java 6 libraries. The <javac> task in Ant does not provide a way to specify your desired version, short of using <fork> and giving the exact path of the bin. The <target> tag only deals with compatibility; it doesn't make an old javac in an old javaroot aware of the jre libraries in some other javaroot.

Comment: Bottom line: I need to compile a program that uses the new Desktop class, and I want the script to warn people when their Java isn't going to cut it. That way they don't get confusing compiler errors about unknown symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Beware, the ant.java.version returns the JDK version with which Ant is built till Ant 1.6.5...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ContainsRegEx task to do regex matching on the java version string. Otherwise, a lot depends upon what you're guarding with this version check. For example, the javac task has ways of specifying the the JVM version you are targeting the built classes for. So, if you decide not to use the conditional approach in your example, it may depend upon what particular tasks support as far as how they work with different JVM versions.